# How to identifiy a set marker on the map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, here-api

I have got a **Map** where I display **Markers** whenever a user clicks on the map in order to draw a **Polygon**. Now I want to allow the user to edit an already set Marker. That means he should be able to klick on the marker and drag it to the desired position.

In order to edit the position of only one Marker I need to identify the one Marker that is being dragged in order to pass the changed position to the according Marker.

I am trying to do this inside the my eventHandler because here I can get some more information for the Marker. Here is one of my handler and the handler where all the updating of the position should happen.

```
[EventUtils.DRAG_END]: (event, details) => {
        const target = event.target;
        if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
          this.disableMapBehaviour = false;
          const id = target.getId();
          this.props.onDrag(details.calculateGeoCoords(), id);
          this.forceUpdate();
        }
```

**My problem is that the `getId()` function always gives me random ID's.** When I set 10 markers for example, this is how the sequence of the Marker ID looks like:

- 1 Marker has ID of 2
- 2 Marker has ID of 3
- 3 Marker has ID of 5
- 4 Marker has ID of 6... and the rest is always different.

Why does the Map set the ID's randomly and not like 1,2,3,4,5... ?

Or what am I doing wrong? Should I use something else than the `event.target.getId()`

Comment: My bad. The map doesn't set the Ids randomly. It was me who did not splice the array of Markers when the dragging was finished. Works fine now with `getId()`.

Answer (score 1):

Summary: The map doesn't set the Ids randomly. It was me who did not splice the array of Markers when the dragging was finished. Works fine now with getId()